# How to unwatch synonym tags

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process, tag-watching

I have watched the tag `[python-3]` on Stack Overflow long ago.

However, it's now the synonym of the tag [`[python-3.x]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/synonyms), and by clicking the tag `[python-3]` will redirect to `[python-3.x]`

**My watch list**

[image: unwatch synonym tag]

Please advise how to remove `[python-3]` out of my watch list, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent hours of looking, here is what I've found.

There is an `Edit` link where you are able to remove existing watched tags and add new tags.

[image]